# Реализация колбеков в С ++ 11  с помощью лямбда-функций

Tags: callback, c++

Добрый вечер, форумчане.

Вот не могу разобраться с таким вот вопросом:
реализация колбеков с помощью лямбда-функций в С ++ 11, а именно принцип построения такой системы и выигрыши по сравнению с передачей указателя на класс с функционалом.

Все мои попытки воспроизвести данный механизм сводились к передаче указателя на некоторый класс, в котором, в свою очередь, содержались указатели на лямбда-функции.
и этот некоторый класс реализует механизм колбека.

Не будет ли тот же эффект, если передать указатель на класс с обычными функциями?
Может, я неправильно понял новый подход к построению колбеков в С ++ 11 (с использованием лямбда-функций).

Был бы очень признателен, если кто-то объяснит мне принцип построения такого механизма, его преимущества и недостатки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите.

С точки зрения стороны, вызывающей callback, нет никакой принципиальной разницы между указателем на функцию, указателем на интерфейс (то есть, класс, у которого известно, какую функцию вызывать), и лямбда-функцией. Здесь всё просто: это нечто, что нужно вызвать в нужный момент (или нужные моменты) времени.

Однако с точки зрения стороны, предоставляющей callback, есть большая разница. Эта разница не семантическая, а скорее синтаксическая: вам не нужно определять целый класс лишь для того, чтобы вызвать из него один метод и хранить в нём промежуточные данные. Таким образом, у вас исчезает лишняя, ненужная, отвлекающая сущность в программе. (И вам не придётся тратить время на понимание ненужных деталей реализации.)

Пример. Пусть у вас есть дерево `tree<T>`, состоящее из узлов типа `T`, и метод обхода `traverse`. Пусть вам нужно подсчитать, например, количество узлов дерева и произведение всех значений в узлах.

---

С классами ваша задача реализуется так:

На стороне `tree<T>`:

```
// определяем интерфейс
template <typename T>
class NodeCallback
{
public:
    void visit(T& node) = 0;
};

// определяем функцию обхода
template <typename T>
class tree
{
public:
    void traverse(NodeCallback<T>* visitor);

    // ну и остальная реализация дерева
};
```

На стороне клиента:

```
template <typename T>
class NodeCounter : public NodeCallback<T>
{
    size_t count;
public:
    NodeCounter() : count(0) {}
    void visit(T& node) { count++; }
    size_t GetResult() { return count; }
};

class DoubleNodeValueMultiplier : public NodeCallback<double>
{
    double product;
public:
    DoubleNodeValueMultiplier() : product(1.0) {}
    void visit(int& node) { product *= node; }
    double GetResult() { return product; }
};

tree<double> t;

NodeCounter nc;
t.traverse(&nc);
auto countNodes = nc.GetResult();

DoubleNodeValueMultiplier mult;
t.traverse(&mult);
auto product = mult.GetResult();
```

---

Теперь посмотрите, как реализуется такая же функциональность с лямбдами:

На стороне `tree<T>`:

```
// интерфейс не нужен
// определяем функцию обхода
template <typename T>
class tree
{
public:
    void traverse(std::function<void(T&)>& visitor);
    // ну и остальная реализация дерева
};
```

На стороне клиента:

```
// классы не нужны
tree<double> t;

size_t nodeCount = 0;
t.traverse([&nodeCount](auto& node){ nodeCount++; });

double product = 1.0;
t.traverse([&product](auto& node){ product *= node; });
```

---

Несмотря на то, что смысл вычислений тот же самый, выглядят они существенно легковеснее.